# How can I prove the following with natural deduction rules? $¬∀x∃yP(x,y) ⊢ ∃x∀y¬P(x,y)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have been stuck with this problem for a long time, I tried reductio ad absurdum and I got the hypothesys $[¬∃x∀y¬P(x,y)]$, then I try to eliminate the negation of the premise, but I have to prove $∀x∃yP(x,y)$, and after using the introduction of universal quantifier rule, I go again with reductio ad absurdum, gaining a second hypothesis $[¬∃yP(x,y)]$. But at this point I have two hypothesis that contain negations of existencial quantifier, and I don't know how to use them constructively.
I found some other similar questions, but all the answers given do not say which rules must be applied, and since I'm a beginner I didn't understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this exactly right! You just have to derive $\forall y \neg P(x,y)$ from $\neg \exists y P(x,y)$

Now, I am not sure how your proof system defines the rule for $\forall$ Introduction ... in the system that I use you designate a 'fresh' constant to take the role of the arbitrary object from the domain. So this is what it looks like in my preferred system, called Fitch:

[image]

Comment: How did you build such proof, @Bram28?
Did you use any software?

Comment: @lucasbbs  Yes, this is a software program called Fitch. It is part of a commercial book+software package called Language, Proof, and Logic.... so it costs money. There are some free proofs editors out there though, e.g. https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Hey, @Bram28, I just bought that software, However I cannot use it to prove ⊢ ∃y∀x P(x,y) →  ∀x∃y P(x,y) since I do not have any premise...

Actually I don't know how to use the program. How can I do that?

Comment: @lucasbbs There should be a ‘Add Premise’ feature … under Proof I believe. The short-cut key is CTRL-R. Also make sure you are inAuthor mode… that’s under Edit. Also, there is a user manual that came with the software … and there are video manuels on the LPL website

Comment: I have the following question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425319/how-to-prove-that-vdash-exists-y-forall-px-y-rightarrow-forall-x-exists ... Could you please help me address such question?