# How to prove that $\vdash \exists y \forall x P(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ with natural deduction in tree style

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I have built the following proof for $\vdash \exists y \forall x P(x,y)  \rightarrow \forall x \exists y P(x,y)$ with natural deduction in tree style.

However, I am stuck in the middle of the problem... How can I conclude the right subtree of $∀_x P(x,y)$ ?

[image]

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I have edited my question... Maybe now I made everything clearer.

Comment: No, it is not... You started (top left) with the assumption $∀x∃yP(x,y)$, but that must be the conclusion.

Comment: I want to write it using natural deduction

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I have rewritten that again, but I am still stuck in the middle of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start assuming $∃y∀xP(x,y)$ and we will derive $∀x∃yP(x,y)$. The result follows by $(\to \text I)$.

1. $∃y∀xP(x,y)$ --- premise
2. $∀xP(x,a)$ --- start sub-proof for $(\exists \text E)$: assumption [a] from 1), with $a$ new
3. $P(z,a)$ --- from 2) by $(\forall \text E)$
4. $∃yP(z,y)$ --- from 3) by $(\exists \text I)$.
5. $∀x∃yP(x,y)$ --- from 4) by $(\forall \text I)$: the [proviso of the rule](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#H7) is satisfied because the variable we are "generalizing" is not free in the assumptions.

Having derived a formula with no occurrence of parameter used in assumption [a], the [proviso for $(\exists \text E)$](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#H7) is satisfied and we can close the sub-proof and discharge temporary assumption [a], concluding with:

> 6. $∀x∃yP(x,y)$ --- from 2)-5) and 1) by $(\exists \text E)$.

Comment: Could you write it as a tree please?

Comment: Please, notice that the rule for ∃e in the link you provided requires a subproof also for a formula $\varphi$

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag3k_3qwTcupzEj7Rir2Cq8qx9Pe

Comment: @lucasbbs - it si quite difficult to format the proof here, but the task is very easy on paper. You have almost it on your picture: cut out the rightmost part of the tree, the step deriving $\bot$ because useless.